# closed formula for a series

Tags: pattern-recognition

The first column below is n (iterator), the second is the value, I'm trying to understand if there is a closed formula that I can use for obtaining the value given a fixed n

$$n=0:  a$$
$$n=1:  a(y-1) + 1$$
$$n=2:  a(y^2-2y+2)-2$$
$$n=3:  a(y^3-3y^2+6y-6)+6$$
$$n=4:  a(y^4-4y^3+12y^2-24y+24)-24$$

Comment: I have no idea what the expression above is meant to mean?

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for looking, I think the formatting got weird..I'm trying to figure out how to left align it so it would look better

Comment: Why do you use $a$? Surely it should be $\int_0^y e^x dx = e^y-1$.

Comment: @copper.hat I made an edit to use e^y instead. also I need a closed form (or maybe a summation or something), but not integral

Comment: $$y^3 - 3y^2 + 6y - 6 = 3!\left(\frac{y^3}{3!} - \frac{y^2}{2!} + \frac{y}{1!} - 1\right)$$

Comment: @achille hui, this does not work for 4..

Comment: @achille hui, actually maybe it does..

Comment: @achille hui, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\beta$ be any number with $|\beta| < 1$. Notice

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\beta^n}{n!} \int_0^y x^n e^{x} dx
&= \int_0^y e^{(1+\beta)x} dx
= \frac{1}{1+\beta}\left(e^{(1+\beta)y} - 1\right)\\
&= \left[\sum_{p=0}^\infty(-1)^p\beta^p\right]\left[e^y\left(\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{\beta^q}{q!}y^q\right)-1\right]
\end{align}
$$
By comparing coefficients of $\beta^n$ on both sides, we get

$$\int_0^y x^n e^x dx = n! \left[ e^y \left( \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-q}}{q!}y^q\right) - (-1)^n\right]\tag{*1}$$

**Ideas behind such a closed form**

To shine some light why the closed from looks like this, let us re-derive the integral in a completely bogus manner. It is known that for any smooth function $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$, we have 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big[ f(x) e^x \Big] = ( f(x) + f'(x) ) e^x\tag{*2}$$

If we view $\displaystyle\;D = \frac{d}{dx}\;$ as some sort of operator over the space of smooth functions. $(*2)$ can be reinterpreted as

$$ L^{-1} D L = D + 1$$
where $L$ is the operator of pointwise multiplication a function by $e^x$. In certain sense,
integration is the inverse of differentiation. Expression of the form

$$e^{-y} \int^y e^{x} f(x) dx\tag{*3}$$

can be interpreted as applying the operator

$$L^{-1} D^{-1} L = ( L^{-1} D L )^{-1} = (1 + D)^{-1}$$
to the function $f$. If we close our eyes and expand

$$(1 + D)^{-1} = 1 - D + D^2 + D^3 - \ldots...$$
We get a formal expression for the integral

$$\int^y f(x) e^x dx = e^y ( f(y) - f'(y) + f''(y) - \ldots ) + \text{constant}\tag{*4}$$

Even though the logic is bogus, if we apply this to $f(x) = x^n$, we reproduce the formula $(*1)$.

In certain sense, $(*4)$ can be viewed as the result of repeatedly applying
integration by parts to $f(x)$. When $f(x)$ is a polynomial, the chain of integration by parts terminated in finite steps and we get back another polynomial multiplying $e^x$.
That's why $(*4)$ works when $f(x)$ is a polynomial and why $(*1)$ have such a form.

Comment: how did you know this? Is this a known structure? Is there a name for it?

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients are known as the falling factorial triangle, $T(N,K)=\frac{N!}{(N-K)!}$:

```
1 
1, 1 
1, 2, 2   
1, 3, 6, 6    
1, 4, 12, 24, 24  
1, 5, 20, 60, 120, 120 
1, 6, 30, 120, 360, 720, 720 
1, 7, 42, 210, 840, 2520, 5040, 5040 
1, 8, 56, 336, 1680, 6720, 20160, 40320, 40320
```